# Microsoft VisualStudio TestTools UITest dll

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2010

I need to find

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.dll
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Firefox.dll
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Silverlight.dll
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll

Where are these dll located so I can reference it on my project  and i am using visual studio 2010 professional.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2013, CodedUI is only available in the premium and ultimate editions.

For Visual Studio 2015, it's only [available in the enterprise edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx).

Comment: From [this MSDN discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e97fab8-02a6-4a8f-aa86-4440093db214/microsoftvisualstudiotesttoolsuitesting-dll?forum=vsautotest) it appears you may also need the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/gg269474%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies if you have premium or ultimate installed.