# How can the same Coded ui script runs fine on my local dev environment but error out my agent server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I currently have a a script that works fine on my local environment and also on a co-workers local environment. The issue I'm having is when i build it and run it on the agent server i'm receiving the error

```
SearchProperties: 
Name: Name Value: Application Manager
Name: ControlType Value: TreeItem
```

> Exception: System.ArgumentException: No search information has been
>   specified. To search for a control, you must specify one or more
>   search properties or filter properties. Parameter name:
>   SearchProperties    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.ValidateSearchProperties()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.get_UIObject()......

Mouse double click on Wintree item

```
Mouse.DoubleClick(appManag);
```

Type of Application;
- This is on windows application (MSAA)
- The test did run at one point on the server agent but stop working and getting
 this error for some unknown reason

**What I've tried so far**

1. Run the same solution that works on my local environment on the agent server. It works fine on my local server and doesnt on the agent server.
2. Change the coding multiple times and tested on my local server and run same code again on agent server. Still same error message.
3. I've googled and the closest thing i found was [this related post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c50a12a5-2202-46a7-aa3d-a66cea5f7ed9/coded-ui-test-giving-error-systemargumentexception-no-search-information-has-been-specified-to?forum=vsautotest) That post wasn't the exact problem and I tried changing the code some more and it didnt' help.
4. From the QTAgent iTrace the first message i see is on the line is "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extention.IE.XmlSerializers, Version = 12.0.0.0, I don't know why this would be an issue or how to compare it to my workspace?
5. Lastly the weird thing about this is that at one point my test did work on the server agent.
6. I've compared my local version of VS with my agent environment the versions  are the same except the .NET version are different my .NET version on my agent is 4.5.51650 and the .NET version on my local machine is 4.5.51209.

Well if anyone has experience this and can point me in the right direction i'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks

Will

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the UI Test Tools Assembly (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll) on the agent.

Which version of Visual Studio do you have installed on the agent? According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106251/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-uitest-dll) you'll need VS2013 Premium or Ultimate or VS2015 Enterprise.

Comment: I have VS2013 Premium installed. looking on my local machine i do see that assembly.  I looked on the Agent server it seems i only have to folders under the IDE folder those are CommonExtensions and PrivateAssemblies.  I'm going to copy those needed files and folders from my local to the agent server to see if that resolves the issue.. Thanks